# How to use latex in R

Tags: r, latex, expression

I am not sure if this is latex form but Which packages or which process I need to follow to write this in the expression form.

$\text{GPA}=f(H, \text{SAT}, \text{PCT})$

Comment: In R no, but you can use this in Rstudio when generating a markdown report. Also, stackoverflow does not allow latex.

Comment: Are you looking for `$\mathrm{GPA}=f(H, \mathrm{SAT}, \mathrm{PCT})$`?

Comment: Yes, I do it in R studio and I wanna write this. I did it before but I don't remember anymore. Should I use a package for this?

Comment: You should use an RMarkdown file, not an R file.